# How do I know, the thread is finished in Kotlin?

Tags: multithreading, android-studio, kotlin

Im trying to set text after all threads are finished.
Do you have any ideas for me?

```
fun threadStart(){
var ende = 150_000
val s = Semaphore(1)

var thread1 :Thread = Thread(Runnable{
    while(counter < ende){
        counter++
        println("1. Thread : $counter")
        println("${Thread.currentThread().name} 1. Thread  $counter")
    }
    if(counter == ende) {
        while (counter != 0) {
            counter--

            println("${Thread.currentThread().name} der Minus counter $counter")
            s.release()
        }
    }
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread3.start()
thread4.start()
```

Normally I would write a print after thread4 here or in the main after threadstart()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you asking how to make the main thread *wait* for the other threads to finish? If so, you can do that with:

```kotlin
thread1.join()
thread2.join()
thread3.join()
thread4.join()
```